# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. (Laravel)

Tags: php, apache, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to install laravel and applying the command

**composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog**

I get the following error ... What could it be?

> ```
> Problem 1
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.9 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.8 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.7 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.6 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.5 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.43 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.42 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.40 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.4 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.39 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.38 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.37 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.36 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.35 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.34 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.33 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.32 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.31 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.30 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.3 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.29 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.28 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.27 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.26 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.25 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.24 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.23 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.22 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.21 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.20 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.19 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.18 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.17 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.16 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.15 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.14 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.13 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.12 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.11 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.10 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework v5.2.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - laravel/framework 5.2.41 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>     - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.2.41, v5.2.0, v5.2.1, v5.2.10,
> ```
>
> v5.2.11, v5.2.12, v5.2.13, v5.2.14, v5.2.15, v5.2.16, v5.2.17,
>   v5.2.18, v5.2.19, v5.2.2, v5.2.20, v5.2.21, v5.2.22, v5.2.23, v5.2.24,
>   v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.29, v5.2.3, v5.2.30, v5.2.31,
>   v5.2.32, v5.2.33, v5.2.34, v5.2.35, v5.2.36, v5.2.37, v5.2.38,
>   v5.2.39, v5.2.4, v5.2.40, v5.2.42, v5.2.43, v5.2.5, v5.2.6, v5.2.7,
>   v5.2.8, v5.2.9].
>
> ```
>   To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
>   You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
> ```

Comment: The `mbstring` extension for php is missing, you have to enable that in your `php.ini` file and restart your webserver

Comment: I have uncommented the extension of mbstring in my php.ini and I restart the server, not solvented :((

Comment: Make sure you were editing the correct php.ini.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the laravel docs 5.1 :https://laravel.com/docs/5.1#installation